# Is it necessary to check ergodicity in estimation of autocorrelation function?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, ergodic

Given a sample path from a process supposed to be stationary, I saw the sample autocorrelation function of the sample path is used to estimate the autocorrelation function of the process. But this requires that the stationary process is ergodic. So

- is ergodicity  checked on the sample path before estimation of the autocorrelation function? If yes, how is ergodicity checked?
- is the estimation done assuming ergodicity without checking it, and after the estimation, testing/checking if the estimation fits the data? If yes, how is the testing done?

A side question: how is stationarity is tested for estimation of autocorrelation function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check ergodicity of a stochastic processes from its sample path(s)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83808/how-do-you-check-ergodicity-of-a-stochastic-processes-from-its-sample-paths)

Comment: The side Q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182764/stationarity-tests-in-r-checking-mean-variance-and-covariance   and search this site