# How do I test a (mathematical) system of equations for ergodicity?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, ergodic

I have a set of equations, which I can plot in for example Matlab.

I would like to test for ergodicity: how can I do this?

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83808/how-do-you-check-ergodicity-of-a-stochastic-processes-from-its-sample-paths) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140910/how-to-detect-if-ergodicity-stationarity-and-martingale-dif-sequence), but it is not very clear to me how I can check for ergodicity using a set of equations AND/OR which plot I should make to see whether the mathematical system is ergodic or not.